# WCF Error: Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, c#-4.0, web-config

I want to publish a Webservice with basicHttpBinding configuration. I am using a basicHttpBinding configuration to increase the default message size of 65536 bytes. The problem I am having is that when I use the web.config settings as shown below, I am getting an error:

> Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.

My Main goal is to be able to increase the default message size and able to save binary file in database, therefore any other config is welcome, however I was trying to keep it as simple as possible to avoid further issues.

Can you please spot what is wrong with my configuration?
Service.config code is below..

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpEndpointBinding" closeTimeout="01:01:00"
          openTimeout="01:01:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646"
          messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="StreamedRequest"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483646"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
     <services>
        <service name="WITSService.WITSService"  behaviorConfiguration="DragDrop.Service.ServiceBehavior" >
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpEndpointBinding" contract="DragDrop.Service.IService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <!--<services>
      <service name="WITSService.WITSService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WITSService.WITSService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>-->

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DragDrop.Service.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this configuration in your web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="4800" maxRequestLength="2097150"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding/>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="LargeSilverlight" closeTimeout="00:21:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:50:00">
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client/>
    <!--SERVICE-->
    <services>
      <service name="WITSService.WITSService" behaviorConfiguration="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeSilverlight" behaviorConfiguration="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication" contract="DragDrop.Service.IService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <!--BEHAVIOR-->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Sanjeetharan.. What type of settings i need to put in web.config..means Client web.config

Comment: You don't have to put anything. Once you add the reference it will be automatically created.

Comment: Is it in the client side or service side? what is your client? silverlight or asp.net? and why don't you try with WCFTESTCLIENT

Comment: It should work then. Did you put the webconfig which i posted here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21947/discussion-between-mindfresher-and-sajeetharan)